# ¿Cómo integro el método explode correctamente aquí en este código?

Tags: php, html, laravel, blade

Quiero tomar la variable `Areas` que viene de mi tabla `$projects` e integrar el método `explode` .

Esto es lo que tengo en vista:

```php
@foreach($projects as $project)
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">¿Como mejorar? Empresa tipo 1</h5>
            <h6 class="card-title">Límite de registro:</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{ $project->Cierre }}</p>
            <h6 class="card-title">Área Académica:</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{ $project->Areas }}</p>
            <h6 class="card-title">Campus sede: </h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{ $project->Sede }}</p>
            <h6 class="card-title">Alcance:</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{ explode(',',$project->Alcance }}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Abrir</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], realiza el [tour] y provee un [mcve]

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende en lo absoluto, por favor para evitar su cierre trata de que la misma responda a esto: ¿qué problema tienes?, ¿qué has intentado para resolverlo?, una muestra de los datos de entrada y una muestra de los datos que esperas de salida

Comment: no se como explicarlo, puedo hablarle por email?

Comment: No, para eso es la plataforma, por favor redacta tu pregunta atendiendo a los puntos mencionados, por que no nos dices que le quieres hacer a ese string, como viene y como esperas que quede

Comment: Que tal ahora? esta mejor?

Comment: explode retorna un array, que es lo que quieres desplegarle al usuario exactamente ?

Comment: projects es mi tabla que esta en mi base de datos, lo que quiero es enviar mi tabla por medio del controlador y en el codigo de la vista con un foreach desglosar todos los campos de la tabla project

Comment: ahora lo que busco es como enviar la tabla de mi base datos como un parametro en mi controlador  y poder usarlo en la vista que se esta retornando, no se si me explique